# Unable to log into M365 Apps - Event ID: 36871 A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10011

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I am unable to authenticate to M365 Apps and getting the following errors. I cant seem to find any information regarding this specific error - Event ID: 36871 A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10011.

Any input help, thanks!

[image]

Tried enabling TLS1.2 - No success.
Tried the following GPOs : No Success

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Cloud Content – Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft account – Block all consumer Microsoft account user authentication

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OneDrive – Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage